# Cypress - delete all rows from table

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am writing a set of tests on a list of elements (HTML table).

Since the tests are still a work in progress, I'm getting a lot of junk data which I'd like to cleanup before each run.

So, I'm trying to delete all rows in `before()` hook. I imagine the process for deleting should be:

1. Search products by name
2. Click a delete icon in first row
3. Wait for confirmation dialog
4. Click "Yes"
5. Repeat from step `2` until there are no rows left

This is the function I've got so far that I call after typing in the search input:

```
 function deleteAllFoundProducts() {
        cy.get('tbody tr').then(rows => {
            if (rows.length < 1) return // if no rows remain, terminate recursion
            cy.get('span[title="Delete"]', {timeout: 10000}).first().click()
            cy.get('.tBtn[title="Yes"]').click().then(() => {
                cy.get('.loader', {timeout: 10000}).should('not.exist') // wait for list to reappear
                deleteAllFoundProducts() // try again
            })
        })
    }
```

The problem is – the function continues to run even after deleting the final row, and errors out because there is no `span[title="Delete"]`.

**[EDIT]**

On closer inspection I realized that an empty table still has one row – with *No records found* text. I thought it wasn't a row at all. So, the error is caused by having a row that doesn't contain a delete icon. I should have noticed that sooner.

This is relevant HTML with unnecessary Angular stuff removed:

```
<tbody class="p-element p-datatable-tbody" ng-reflect-value="" ng-reflect-template="[object Object]">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <my-loader ng-reflect-loading="false">
            </my-loader>
            <div class="p-2">No matching records found. </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The solution would, I guess, be to check if the row contains an element with text 'No records found', and perform delete only if it doesn't. But I'm not sure how to do it. Any help would still be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the HTML for your table ?

Comment: Have you thought about deleting data from the backend instead (assuming you're using one)? i.e. by exposing an endpoint that deletes data, then calling that endpoint in your Cypress lifecycle hooks. That way you can keep your test cases relatively simple.

Answer (score 2):

With this recursive function you just need to pass a variable that decrements (or maybe increments to a max)

```js
function deleteAllFoundProducts(rowCount) {
  if (rowCount < 1) return // if no rows remain, terminate recursion
  cy.get('span[title="Delete"]', {timeout: 10000}).first().click()
  cy.get('.tBtn[title="Yes"]').click().then(() => {
    cy.get('.loader', {timeout: 10000}).should('not.exist') // wait for list to reappear
    deleteAllFoundProducts(--rowCount) // try again
  })
}

cy.get('tbody tr')
  .then(rows => deleteAllFoundProducts(rows.length))  // first call here
```

This will still work when there's a *"No matching records found"* row appended after deleting all rows, since `rowCount` is obtained before deletions start.

Comment: This won't work if the table is initially empty (i.e. *only* `No matching records found` is displayed).

Comment: @dzenesiz yes, don't do it if the table is empty! That's the nature of Cypress commands - they cannot be conditional.

Comment: Cypress recommends knowing ***exactly what data*** the test is dealing with.

Comment: so, you're saying there is actually no point in developing a functionality that "cleans up the junk data" since junk data should never happen in the first place? :)

Comment: If there's nothing to clean, my solution won't work. You can always check how many rows there are using jQuery, something like `const rowcount = Cypress.${'tbody tr').length`

Comment: Oh, yeah - sorry you were responding to my rant about deterministic tests. Maybe, but then would you not want a simple cleanup of the db between test?

Comment: Sounds like it...

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is the safer way to iterate, particulary when the DOM is changed during the the loop or there is a conditional part to the test. Using `.each()` can give you "detached from DOM" errors.

There's a library https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse that makes it a bit easier.

You might apply it like ths

```js
import { recurse } from 'cypress-recurse'

before(() => {
  recurse(
    () => {
      return cy.get('tbody tr').eq(0).then($row => {
        const $deleteButton = $row.find('button[title="Delete"]')
        if ($deleteButton.length) {
          $deleteButton[0].click()
        }
        return $deleteButton   // return this to signal end of iteration
      })
    },
    ($deleteButton) => $deleteButton.length === 0  // end if no delete button
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is an assumption, if this is not working then I would need to see the HTML table, So what I am assuming is that in your table you have different rows and in each row you have a Delete button and once you delete the button the row is removed. You can use an inbuilt cypress command `each()`.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
    cy.get('span[title="Delete"]', {timeout: 10000}).first().click()
  })
  cy.get('.tBtn[title="Yes"]').click()
  cy.get('.loader', {timeout: 10000}).should('not.exist')
})
```

Or, when there is 'No Records found' displayed, just exit the loop.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr').each(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.find('div.p-2').text().trim().includes('No records found')) {
    return false
  } else {
    cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
      cy.get('span[title="Delete"]', {timeout: 10000}).first().click()
    })
  cy.get('.tBtn[title="Yes"]').click()
  cy.get('.loader', {timeout: 10000}).should('not.exist')
  }
})
```

Comment: I actually found out that 'No records found' message is also a `tr`. 
Your answer works except in that case. I edited my question above. 
Would it be a bother to update your answer so I can accept it? 

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. 
Unfortunately, it never enters the `if` block, so it still errors out.

Comment: Please share your HTML. In that way I can rectify the code correctly.

Comment: Is the text 'No records find' under `td` element? Yes it is expected as $ele is a jquery element

Comment: Just added HTML in my question above.

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you try ?